# aspect based sentiment using NLTK?

Tags: python, classification, nltk, sentiment-analysis

I'm working on Aspect Based sentiment analysis. I have a training set (text ,and aspectTerms) for each review.

Using NLTK3, I want to build a Naive Bayes Classifier that predicts aspects of unseen test data. I will use a feature Part of speech tagging of aspects.

What does the feature method look like? How do I train the classifier? How to test the classifier on unseen data?

I tried the following:

My feature function looks like

```
def featurepos(word):
    return dict(wordpos,true)  //return part of speech tagging for a given word
```

and built a classifier as

```
classifier=NaiveBayesClassifier.train(train_set)
#train_set contains [(posofaspect,"aspect")]
```

Now I want to test the classifier with test data.

To check the accuracy, the code below required `test_set`

```
nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier,test_set)
```

`test_set` is a list of dictionaries? If it's a dict what is the its structure? -I'm confused.
If there is an example it would be so helpful!

Comment: What's `wordpos`? What is the relationship between a word, its PoS, and the "aspect"? Can you point to any background to help us understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: I found http://alt.qcri.org/semeval2014/task4/ to briefly explain what I believe to be the task here. But it's not at all obvious how a Bayesian classifier and PoS tags fit into the big picture. Please explain your approach.

Comment: POS is part of speech tagging . I want to build a classifier to extract aspects from a test set. Aspects are the keywords in a text and they are likely to be Nouns . So I have already the train set text with aspects.

Comment: So you extract nouns for aspects, and, what, verbs and adjectives and adverbs for sentiments? How do you determine a sentiment and how do you decide which aspect it describes? Or do you simply assume one sentence, one sentiment, one aspect?

Comment: More concretely, in your `featurepos` function, you have an unbound or global variable `wordpos`. What is it and where does it come from?

Comment: Sorry I didn't write the body of the function ,it takes the part of speech tag from the given parameter (word).

Comment: My problem is to understand the parameter that sent with the classifier. train_set should be a dictionary as I understand. what about test_set!,, can it be a list.?

Comment: tripleee ,this type of sentiment works on aspect level ,so instead of taking the whole sentence ,just pick up some keywords(aspects) and determine their polarities as well as determine the category of the whole sentence and its polarity...I use a supervised learning with an annotated data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what the accuracy function does, as per the [documentation](http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/classify/util.html#accuracy):

```
def accuracy(classifier, gold):
    results = classifier.classify_many([fs for (fs,l) in gold])
    correct = [l==r for ((fs,l), r) in zip(gold, results)]
    if correct:
        return float(sum(correct))/len(correct)
    else:
        return 0
```

Test set is therefore a list of tuples (features, corresponding labels) and the function (1) uses the trained classifier to compute the outputs on those features, (2) confront the classification results with the given labels and (3) output the hit ratio

Comment: I don't understand why I get the accuracy =1.0!? after using :  nltk.classify.util.accuracy(classifier,test_set)

Comment: It means the classifier is getting the correct answer for all tuples in the provided `test_set`.

Comment: This is impossible to happen using only one feature and NaiveBayes.!

Comment: Most likely it is a problem with your test set. It doesn't invalidate the answer to your original question though.